# How to get custom product attribute values in magento 2 jquery?

Tags: magento2, checkout, attributes, product-attribute, jquery

I want to get custom product attribute ('deliverytime') values for  checkout config in jquery

Here is the code for  getting default product attributes jquery

**date-block.js**

```
 function updateDeliveryDateAndTime() {
                if($('#delivery_date').length && window.checkoutConfig && window.checkoutConfig.quoteItemData) {

                    console.log(checkoutConfig.quoteItemData);
                    //read checkoutconfig
                    var quoteData = checkoutConfig.quoteItemData,
                        quote_length = quoteData.length,
                      prep_times = [],
                      creation_dates = [],
                      cake_names = [],
                      item_ids = [];
                    console.log(quoteData[0].deliverytime); // **this shows undefined**
```

> in checkoutconfig.quoteItemdata  has  no  custom attributes are
>   showing
>
> checked in console

could anyone help me to resolve the problem..

Answer (score 0):

Use your same product object `$obj->getDatetime();`
get is appended to your fields name (you see in admin on inspecting the element)

So if you fields is `product['datetimevalue']` . Then syntac would be `getDatetimevalue();`

Assign this value to one of the div element.
In jquery just pull value and show.

Comment: yeah   it's  good but need by  step by step

points

Comment: i no need to print that values i want to use for checkout process

Comment: Create custom field similar to https://webkul.com/blog/add-custom-field-checkout-address-form-magento2/  . Value you will get form above mentioned format.

Comment: no  i created that attribute in

store->attributes   ->  product
no need to show in checkout form